# Overflowed container with WebView on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to fix the bottom overflowed by WebView into a Container()? The _getDescription method is into a Column Widget and Expanded Widget but the it is overflowed the container().

The _getDescription method is returning a WebView instance from HtmlWidget plugin. My code:

```
Widget _getBody(tittle, date, description, origin, context) {
return new Container(
  margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  child: Expanded(
    child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        _getTittle(tittle),
        _getDate(date, origin),
        _getDescription(description),
        _getImageGallery(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}

_getDescription(description) {
return new Container(
  margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, bottom: 4.0),
  child: HtmlWidget(
    description,
    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.5),
    webView: true,
  ),
);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SingleChildScrollView(child: Column(...))` instead of `Expanded()`

Comment: It has no effect. Remembering that getBody Widget is located into a Scaffold Widget

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue. You can use replace the `Expanded` widget with `SingleChildScrollView`. Another way is to use `ListView`.

Or, if you don't want to scroll the overflowed text, use `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` inside the `Text` widget on the `_getDescription` method

Comment: When I replace Expanded to SingleChildScrollView makes WebView blank :(. Replacing Column to ListView got not effects as well

Comment: use a container as a parent of the `ListView` to provide a valid height and width for `ListView`